# How can I erase my objects in the drawing application without changing the Background Image?

Tags: android

I want to erase my bitmap but I don't want to erase background image. When I try to erase is white and it draw very hard in frames.

this is my MainActivity code

```
    private final String tag = "MainActivity";

    private ImageView eraser;
    private Button btnChooseImage;
    private ImageButton btnClear, btnSave, btnShare, btnCamera;

    private DrawingView drawingView;

    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            drawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);

            btnChooseImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseImage);
            btnChooseImage.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnClear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
            btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnSave = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnShare = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
            btnShare.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
            btnCamera.setOnClickListener(this);

            eraser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraser);
            eraser.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }





    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == eraser) {

            if (drawingView.isEraserActive()) {

                drawingView.deactivateEraser();

                eraser.setImageResource(R.drawable.eraser);

            } else {

                drawingView.activateEraser();

                eraser.setImageResource(R.drawable.pencil);
            }

        } else if (v == btnClear) {

            drawingView.reset();
            drawingView.setBackground(null);

        } else if (v == btnSave) {

            saveImage();

        } else if (v == btnCamera) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        } else if (v == btnShare) {

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/png");

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(saveImage().getAbsolutePath())); //"file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

        } else if (v == btnChooseImage) {

            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);

        }

    }


    public File saveImage() {
        drawingView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bm = drawingView.getDrawingCache();

        File fPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File f = null;

        f = new File(fPath, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png");

        try {
            FileOutputStream strm = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, strm);
            strm.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image is saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return f;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = null;
                    try {
                        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                        BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                        {
                            drawingView.setBackground(ob);
                        }else {
                            drawingView.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
                        }

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");

                    BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo);

                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                    {
                        drawingView.setBackground(ob);
                    }else {
                        drawingView.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
                    }
                }
        }
    }


}
```

and here is the DrawingView code

```
private Canvas m_Canvas;

    private Path m_Path;

    private Paint m_Paint;

    private ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> paths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();

    private ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();

    private float mX, mY;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0.001f;

    private boolean isEraserActive = false;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        setFocusable(true);

        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        onCanvasInitialization();
    }

    public void onCanvasInitialization() {

        m_Paint = new Paint();
        m_Paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        m_Paint.setDither(true);
        m_Paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
        m_Paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        m_Paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        m_Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        m_Canvas = new Canvas();


        m_Path = new Path();
        Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint);
        paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Pair<Path, Paint> p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
        }
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

        if (isEraserActive) {
            m_Paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
            paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));

        } else { 
            m_Paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
            paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));

        }


        m_Path.reset();
        m_Path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            m_Path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        m_Path.lineTo(mX, mY);

        // commit the path to our offscreen
        m_Canvas.drawPath(m_Path, m_Paint);

        // kill this so we don't double draw
        m_Path = new Path();
        Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
        paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));
    }

    public void activateEraser()
    {
        isEraserActive = true;
    }


    public void deactivateEraser()
    {
        isEraserActive = false;
    }

    public boolean isEraserActive()
    {
        return isEraserActive;
    }


    public void reset()
    {
        paths.clear();

        invalidate();
}
}
```

I wanted to erase the drawing view without changing the background image which is imported from gallery

Answer (score 0):

make one function in your View class and clear all list views you have saved before and redraw the view like:

```
public void clearDrawing()
{
  paths.clear();
  invalidate();
}
```

invalidate() whill refresh the view. Call this method from your view object on click event in activity. Hope it will help.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me.........What exactly i want is when we select an image from gallery to the drawing pad and any objects are drawn in that, only that objects are to be removed not the the gallery image

Comment: You haven't added any image in background in your code! you have used only setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: In my drawing pad i have an option of choose an image from gallery. So that image can be kept as an background image

Comment: So use bitmap to show image in view like canvas.drawBitmap().

Comment: it should erase the pen that is drawn on the image not the background image

Comment: U didn't understand, first draw image bitmap, than pan-what you are saying and than paths list. When you want to erase, onDraw will only draw image. If you want i will update answer.